# Python BeautifulSoup Find data inside a variable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to get some data from website the data is returned as follows

```
window._sharedData = {
  "config": {
    "csrf_token": "DMjhhPBY0i6ZyMKYQPjMjxJhRD0gkRVQ",
    "viewer": null,
    "viewerId": null
  },
  "country_code": "IN",
  "language_code": "en",
  "locale": "en_US"
}
```

How can I import the same into `json.loads` so I can extract the data?

Comment: So shareData is a dictionary? What data are you trying to extract?

Comment: Is this data loaded with ajax or part of the html you get back by say `curl`?

Comment: @iamkhush its in scripts of the html.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I wanna extract the `country_code` or rather if I can get the whole JSON i can play with it. have shortened the JSON for the question.

Comment: `window._sharedData["country_code"]` ?

Comment: @DaniMesejo how do assign the whole thing into a variable in python. right now everything is a text from inside the <script> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it first to a json format by removing the variable name and parsing it as a string:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
text = soup.find('script').text
text = text.replace('window._sharedData = ', '')

data = json.loads(text)
country_code = data['country_code']
```

Or you can use the [eval function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to transform it to a python dictionary. For that you need to replace json types to python and parse it in a dictionary format:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
text = soup.find('script').text

text = text.replace('null', None)
text = text.replace('window._sharedData = ', '')

data = eval(text)
country_code = data['country_code']
```